# Save the output of a function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, save

I have been able to put together the following code to find a time stamp every time space bar is pressed. However, I can't figure out a way to save the S.tm to the work space. Here is the code:

```
function main
    S.tm = [];
    S.cnt = 0;   
    S.fh = figure('KeyPressFcn',@youPressedSomething,...
                  'menu','none',...
                  'pos',[400 400 320 50]);
    S.th = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[10 10 300 30],...
            'String','You have not hit space yet');
 function  youPressedSomething(varargin)
    if strcmp(varargin{2}.Character,' ')
            S.tm = [S.tm now] 
            S.cnt = S.cnt + 1;
            set(S.th,'str',sprintf('You hit space %i!',S.cnt));

    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: isn't it because you do not declare any outputs? see [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html?refresh=true)

Comment: That is what I am unsure about. I haven't used this kind of functionality before, so not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @A_C Would't it return values to workspace only after the `main`function ends? I think one must create handle in workspace, pass it to `main` and then into `yPS` to be updated.

Comment: @Crowley Even when I close the figure, the output doesn't get saved to the work space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main options here. You could use `assignin` *within* your function to save the data to the main workspace.

```
function main
    S.tm = [];
    S.cnt = 0;   
    S.fh = figure('KeyPressFcn',@youPressedSomething,...
                  'menu','none',...
                  'pos',[400 400 320 50]);
    S.th = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[10 10 300 30],...
            'String','You have not hit space yet');

    function  youPressedSomething(varargin)
        if strcmp(varargin{2}.Character,' ')
            S.tm = [S.tm now] 
            S.cnt = S.cnt + 1;

            set(S.th,'str',sprintf('You hit space %i!',S.cnt));

            %// Save as "timestamps" in the base workspace
            assignin('base', 'timestamps', S.tm);

        end
    end
end
```

Or a better approach would be to use [`waitfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitfor.html) to block execution of the function until the figure is closed. Then you can return `S.tm` just like a normal output argument

```
function timestamps = main()
    S.tm = [];
    S.cnt = 0;   
    S.fh = figure('KeyPressFcn',@youPressedSomething,...
                  'menu','none',...
                  'pos',[400 400 320 50]);

    S.th = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[10 10 300 30],...
            'String','You have not hit space yet');

    %// Wait until the figure is closed
    waitfor(S.fh);

    %// Save S.tm as timestamps and return
    timestamps = S.tm;

    function  youPressedSomething(varargin)
        if strcmp(varargin{2}.Character,' ')
            S.tm = [S.tm now] 
            S.cnt = S.cnt + 1;

            set(S.th,'str',sprintf('You hit space %i!',S.cnt));

            %// Save as "timestamps" in the base workspace
            assignin('base', 'timestamps', S.tm);

        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit your code this way:

```
function[S.fh]=main()
%% Your Code

function yPS(varargin)
  if...
  %% Your Code
  end
  set(S.fh,'UserData',S.tm);
end %yPS
end %main
```

This should return figure handle to the workspace and keep it in memory as well. Then whenever the `yPS` function is called it uses shared handle `S.fh` to the figure and (re)sets `UsedData` property which is dedicated to contain, well, user data.

To use the function call it `Foo=main`.

```
get(Foo.fh,'UserData')

ans = 

[]
```

Hit spacebar several times

```
>> get(AA.fh,'userdata')

ans =

1.0e+005 *

  7.3645
  7.3645
  7.3645
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but it shows "tm" as blank. I did make one change to what you suggested.  In [S.fh]=main() , I used [S]=main() because MATLAB didn't like S.fh output.

Comment: Still outputting blank

Comment: I am really confused now. You are saying that I should use function[Fig]=nestie() and call that in a different file, correct? When do I press the spacebar to record the timestamps though?

Comment: When I ran the code, right now its just storing how many times I press space bar but it doesn't record the time, so I will have to edit it accordingly. However, the code works only if you keep the figure open, if its closed, the get(Foo,'UserData') results in an error

Comment: Yes, if you close the figure its data structure is deleted. You can try to save the data using `DeleteFcn` property.

Comment: I am not able to make it output the time stamps. I used the line of code I was using in my original posting.. but can't figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110819/discussion-between-crowley-and-dashd).